# Script Complains that File Cannot be Found When not Looking for it

Tags: powershell, error-handling, windows-7

I have the below function running in a logon script, which checks whether the user has the current version of `IT Self Help.exe`. If the current version is not present, then it should be copied onto the desktop from the `$appsource` folder:

```
function UrgentSupportApp {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    trap {Log-Error $_ $MyInvocation.MyCommand; Return}

    $desktop = $env:USERPROFILE + '\Desktop\'
    $apptarget = $desktop + 'IT Self Help.exe'
    $appsource = '\\file\Administration\Unused\Apps\IT Support App\IT Self Help.exe'

    # Remove the old version of the app "IT Help Request.exe"
    $oldapps = Get-ChildItem $desktop -Filter *"Help Request.exe"
    if ($oldapps.count -gt 0) {Remove-Item $oldapps.PSPath -Force}

    # Copy the new version over if it is not already present
    $currentversion = (Get-Command $appsource).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion 
    if (Test-Path $apptarget) {
        if ((Get-Command $apptarget).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion -ne $currentversion) {
            Copy-Item $appsource $desktop -Force  ##### Line 981 #####
        }
    } else {
        Copy-Item $appsource $desktop -Force
    }
}
```

```
function Log-Error {
    param (
        $error,
        [string]$sub,
        $detail
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    trap {Log-Error $_ $MyInvocation.MyCommand; Return}

    $filename = "\\file\administration\Unused\LogonScriptErrors\$username - $sub - $computername - $(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy-HHmmss).log"

    New-Item $filename -ItemType File -Value "Message: `r`n`t $($error.Exception.Message) `r`n `r`nPosition: `r`n`t $($error.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage) `r`n `r`nSub: `r`n`t $sub `r`n `r`nDetail: `r`n`t $detail"
}
```

For a couple of users, I am seeing this error come through on line 981, char 22 (see the comment above):

```
Could not find file 'C:\Users\USER.NAME\Desktop\IT Self Help.exe'. 
At \\DC\NETLOGON\mainlogon.ps1:981 char:22
+             Copy-Item <<<<  $appsource $desktop -Force
```

However

- The file clearly can be found, as it made it through the fisrt `If` condition `If (Test-Path $apptarget)`.
- If the file couldn't be found, why would the script complain on that line, where we are not even looking for it?

**What is this error trying to tell me?** If the file could not be found, surely the script would just continue into the `Else` statement

Comment: surround with a try / catch block would be my first attempt

Comment: @brad Thanks for your comment. Has the error not already been caught by my error trap at the top? (about to add my `Log-Error` function to the question)

Comment: is it because you're testing for existence of $apptarget but copying $appsource? Can the affected users 'see' the $appsource network share?

Comment: @TechSpud Yes, users can see the network drive. I test `$apptarget`s existence because if it is there then there is no need to copy anything over. By conventional logic, the script should never actually reach line `981` if it "Could not find file", which is why this error is so weird. And then it complains about a file which line `891` does not even operate on...

Comment: Of course, @bassie. Puzzling! Do: Test-Path $apptarget -PathType Leaf; Test-Path $desktop -PathType Container;  yield the expected results? have you tried explicitly naming the params _Path/-LiteralPath & -Destination?

Comment: @TechSpud They do return the expected results, but that is when I manually run the command from a shell. I get the feeling this will be hard to recreate as it is only happening for a few users at logon. My current plan is to just wrap it in a `try/catch` as @brad suggested and see if it gives me any more useful information tomorrow morning! Will also add the explicit param names in there just to be safe - thanks!

Comment: `Copy-Item` has two parameter sets. The first set uses a `path` - `destination` syntax while the second set uses a `destination` - `literalpath` syntax. As you are not specifying the parameter names, I could imagine `Copy-Item` getting confused and using the wrong parameter set and is trying to use `$apptarget` as the source.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks! will take that into consideration when testing it. Any idea why different sets might be used for different users in the same script? (the issue is not affecting all users)

Comment: Only thing I could think of is a different Powershell version. Other that that, no not really?! On the other hand, it wouldn't hurt to explicitly name the parameters. If the problem goes away then that was the issue :)

Comment: Please show the exact, unaltered error message.